# How can I use a string parameter s to create a new LinkedList with the parameter name?

Tags: java, parameters, linked-list, identifier

I am creating a list of Queue that will hold some objects. I would like to create a method that will add a new queue to the list and return a boolean. There should be a String parameter in the method declaration that will add a new queue by the same name to the queue list. I can't use the String parameter as an identifier for a new LinkedList since it's already defined as a String. How can I create this new LinkedList using the string parameter?

```
public boolean addQueue(String s){

LinkedList<Pcb> s = new LinkedList<Pcb>();

QList.add(s);

return true;

}
```

Comment: You have paramater `s` and local variable `s`

Comment: Why do you need to have a `LinkedList` variable` at all? `QList.add(new LinkedList<>());` would suffice.

Comment: You don’t seem to be using the string parameter. What’s the intended use?

Comment: It's an assignment, I need a class to be able to create any number of queue specified by unique parameters. If I didn't add the queue to a list how can I check for unique identifier?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to have a `LinkedList` associated with the name? If so, you'd have to put the lists into a `Map<String, LinkedList<Pcb>>`, e.g. `map.put(s, new LinkedList<>())`.

Comment: Ideally I would like to create a new queue based on the name passed as a parameter. ex. If i call the method addQueue("Ready") it would create a new 'LinkedList' with the name "Ready". Does this make sense?

Comment: What did you mean **unique identifier**? Where did you store it in those lists? Could you give an example?

Comment: I will have a list of LinkedList that I will add to with the method addQueue(String). So calling AddQueue("Ready) should add a new queue to the list with the name "Ready" while also checking that the list does not already have a queue with the name "Ready"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want is as follows. But you don't need to specify the name of each list to be added, you can just use [`List.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) which will use `Object.equals()` for comparison. And it is going to compare the whole content in list, more precisely, it uses `Object.hashCode()` to achieve this. So, I don't think the additional **unique identifier** is required.

**Code snippet**

```
private static List<List<String>> QList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    addQueue(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
    addQueue(Arrays.asList("a","b","c"));
    addQueue(Arrays.asList("c","b","a"));
    addQueue(Arrays.asList("a","c","b"));
    addQueue(Arrays.asList("c","b","a"));

    System.out.println(QList.toString());
}

public static void addQueue(List<String> list){
    if (!QList.contains(list)) {
        QList.add(list);
    }
}
```

**Console output**

> [[a, b, c], [c, b, a], [a, c, b]]